# Double being given wrong value when part of object

Tags: c++, object, vector, double

My code is supposed to be acting like a ATM machine where it can make different type of accounts and keep track of all the transactions and other information in the accounts

My problem is that the double balance which is stored in the BankAccount class which are stored in a vector to keep up with all the different accounts, well when I try and retrieve the balance it gives me "-9.25596e+061" as the balance no matter what I deposited or put in there, or even if it should be zero. The only time I got it to work is when i made balance a global variable but that is pretty much useless for the sake of the program.

activeAcounts is a vector

```
void BankAccount::deposit(double amount, string name)
{
    balance += amount;
    for (int i = 0; i < activeAccounts.size(); i++)
    {
        if (activeAccounts[i].getName() == name)
        {
             activeAccounts[i].setBalance(balance + amount);
        }
    }

}
```

Inquiry is suppose to just return the balance of an account specified by it's name

```
void BankAccount::inquiry(string n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < activeAccounts.size(); i++)
    {
        if (activeAccounts.at(i).getName() == n)
        {
            cout << "Balance: " << activeAccounts[i].getBalance() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but it looks like you're double adding the balance, since you increment it right away but then set the activeAccounts balances to the already-incremented balance + the increment amount again

Answer (score 0):

You are more than likely not initializing `balance` to 0.  Member variables need to be initialized, unlike globals.  You should initialize `balance` in the `BankAccount` constructor.

In addition, since you are using `vector`, if you've coded a copy constructor and assignment operator for `BankAccount`, you need to make sure that `balance` is copied, else your copy will have a bogus `balance` value.

As to the global variable, when you made balance a global variable, global variables are automatically initialized to 0, which is probably why you didn't have a problem when it was made global.